# SoftLayer Java API getAssignedUser() is null

Tags: java, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I use an account, where there are multiple number of users. I would like to display the name of the user who created the ticket. But, it is always returning null. I am trying:

```
ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apikey);
Account.Service service = Account.service(client);
service.setResultLimit(new ResultLimit(1000));
int count=1;
for (Ticket ticket : service.getTickets()) {
    java.util.GregorianCalendar date = ticket.getCreateDate();
    System.out.println(count + " User: " + ticket.getAssignedUser() +  " Ticket # " + ticket.getId() +  " User: " + ticket.getAssignedUserId() + " Title: " + ticket.getTitle() + " Date: " + date.getTime());
    count++;
}
System.out.println("Total tickets on the account: " + service.getLastResponseTotalItemCount());
```

How do I narrow the results for tickets created from Jan 2016 and list the name of the user who created the ticket?
Any help is appreciated.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Expected 'complexType' as first property using the below code:

```
package SoftLayer.TestMyExample;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Account;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Ticket;
import java.util.List;
public class ListSubnets {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Your SoftLayer API username and key.
    String username = "";
    String apikey = "";

    // Get Api Client and SoftLayer_Account service
    ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apikey);
    Account.Service accountService = Account.service(client);
    accountService.withMask().tickets().assignedUser();
    accountService.withMask().tickets().firstUpdate();
    List<Ticket> tickets = accountService.getObject().getTickets();
    System.out.println(tickets.size());
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to format your code better in order for people to be able to help you. This is hard to read.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue, I have success to get tickets.size(). Anyway, your issue is related to this: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/issues/2  Probably you are using a past version of Java Client. The last version is: 0.2.2 (see [SoftLayer API Client for Java](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java)).

Comment: Also, you can try to make the following change in your code:
Account.Service accountService = Account.service(client, new Long(123123));
Replace: 123123 with your accountId.

Comment: 1) No, I am using the latest version. My pom.xml has:   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.softlayer.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>softlayer-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>0.2.2</version>
    </dependency>  2) I am using bluemix account, where there are many users in the same account. Is that making a difference? 3) My SL username and API key is valid. I have placed orders, last week.

Comment: No, there is not difference, you should able to make api calls successfully, there is an issue that I provided. Did you tried to declare the accountId at the moment to specify the accountService? (As the example that I provided here in the comments)

Comment: Same error, with the accountId too. Do you want me to share my project with you?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Java script, the **assignedUser** is the user which is assigned to the ticket, if you want to get the user who created the ticket, take a look the value of "**EditorType**" if it has "USER" value, it means that an user created the ticket, the "**Editor Id**" will return the userId from the user who created the ticket.

```
package Tickets;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Account;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Ticket;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Ruber Cuellar on 5/5/2016.
 */
public class GetTicketsJanuary {

    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to Get Tickets
     */
    public GetTicketsJanuary() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Get Api Client and SoftLayer_Account service
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        Account.Service accountService = Account.service(client);
        accountService.withMask().tickets().assignedUser();
        accountService.withMask().tickets().firstUpdate();

        try {
            List<Ticket> tickets = accountService.getObject().getTickets();
            for(Ticket ticket : tickets)
            {

                if(ticket.getCreateDate().getTime().getYear() == 116 && ticket.getCreateDate().getTime().getMonth() == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Ticket Id: " + ticket.getId() + " Assigned User Id:: " + ticket.getAssignedUserId() + " Assigned Username: " + ticket.getAssignedUser().getUsername() +
                            " Editor Type: " + ticket.getFirstUpdate().getEditorType() + " Editor Id: " + ticket.getFirstUpdate().getEditorId() + " Create date: " + ticket.getCreateDate().getTime());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new GetTicketsJanuary();
    }
}
```

References:

- [SoftLayer_Account::getTickets](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getTickets)

Comment: ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apikey);
    Account.Service accountService = Account.service(client);
    accountService.withMask().tickets().assignedUser();
    accountService.withMask().tickets().firstUpdate();
    List<Ticket> tickets = accountService.getObject().getTickets();
    System.out.println(tickets.size());   I get an exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Expected 'complexType' as first property
 at com.softlayer.api.json.GsonJsonMarshallerFactory$EntityTypeAdapter.read(GsonJsonMarshallerFactory.java:186)

Comment: com.softlayer.api.json.GsonJsonMarshallerFactory$EntityTypeAdapter.read(GsonJsonMarshallerFactory.java:139) at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805) at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:770) at com.softlayer.api.json.GsonJsonMarshallerFactory.fromJson(GsonJsonMarshallerFactory.java:83) at com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient$ServiceProxy.logAndHandleResponse(RestApiClient.java:270) at com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient$ServiceProxy.invokeService(RestApiClient.java:300) at com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient$ServiceProxy.invoke(RestApiClient.java:466)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue with the part of code that you posted, can you provide the full code that you are trying?

Comment: public class ListSubnets {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     // Your SoftLayer API username and key.
  String username = "";
  String apikey = "";
  
  // Get Api Client and SoftLayer_Account service
     ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apikey);
     Account.Service accountService = Account.service(client);
     accountService.withMask().tickets().assignedUser();
     accountService.withMask().tickets().firstUpdate();
     List<Ticket> tickets = accountService.getObject().getTickets();
     System.out.println(tickets.size());
   }
}

Comment: Exception is the same: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Expected 'complexType' as first property
 at com.softlayer.api.json.GsonJsonMarshallerFactory$EntityTypeAdapter.read(GsonJsonMarshallerFactory.java:186)
 at com.softlayer.api.json.GsonJsonMarshallerFactory$EntityTypeAdapter.read(GsonJsonMarshallerFactory.java:139)
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:805)
 at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:770)
 at com.softlayer.api.json.GsonJsonMarshallerFactory.fromJson(GsonJsonMarshallerFactory.java:83)
 at

Comment: at com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient$ServiceProxy.logAndHandleResponse(RestApiClient.java:270)
 at com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient$ServiceProxy.invokeService(RestApiClient.java:300)
 at com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient$ServiceProxy.invoke(RestApiClient.java:466)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getObject(Unknown Source)
 at SoftLayer.TestMyExample.ListSubnets.main(ListSubnets.java:143)

Comment: Edited the original question, with the new code also.